# Vaadin navigator does not work on v7.6.7

Tags: vaadin

Sample code **in 11.9.3. Handling URI Fragment Path in Book of Vaadin** does not working on v7.6.7. It do well on v7.6.6.
 **How make it to work?**
**Page.setUriFragmnet** can do some similar task but it has another problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: As @AndréSchild was suggesting, describe what you did so far and show the relevant code so we don't have to guess what you may have done wrong

Comment: You can see the problem by running the **Section 11.9.3 (Book of Vaadin) sample code**. With Vaadin **7.6.7** release, the code does not work! But with **7.6.6** framework, it works well! Pls type test code and run it then you can see the problem. My analysis is as follow: the **enter of View** called only at the display of the View screen. So the navigateTo of each button click listener does not activate **enter code**, so whole code does not function!

Comment: **At V7.6.8, the problem is solved.** Vaddin may do a wrong patch  at v7.6.7!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use **UriFragmentChangedListener** for the problem.
Within view, use **UI.getCurrent().getPage().setUriFragment("string-fragment",true)**. One tip is to use **!** as first character of fragment string.

Following is typical format of View handler.

```
package kr.re.nsr.secdiv.inseog.navi.testnavi;

import com.vaadin.navigator.View;
import com.vaadin.navigator.ViewChangeListener.ViewChangeEvent;
import com.vaadin.ui.Button;
import com.vaadin.ui.Label;
import com.vaadin.ui.UI;
import com.vaadin.ui.VerticalLayout;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class AdminView extends VerticalLayout implements View {

    static int count = 0;

    Label label = null;

    public AdminView() {

        UI.getCurrent().getPage().addUriFragmentChangedListener(ev -> {
            String fragment = ev.getUriFragment();
            if(!fragment.startsWith("!admin"))
                return;
            label.setValue("Admin : " + count + "/" + fragment);
        });

        setMargin(true);
        setSpacing(true);

        Button btnAAA = new Button("Admin aaa", e -> {
            this.getUI().getPage().setUriFragment("!admin/aaa", true);
        });

        Button btnBBB = new Button("Admin bbb", e -> {
            this.getUI().getPage().setUriFragment("!admin/bbb", true);
        });

        Button btnQuery = new Button("Goto query", e -> {
            TestNavi.navigator.navigateTo("query");
        });

        label = new Label();

        addComponent(btnAAA);
        addComponent(btnBBB);
        addComponent(btnQuery);
        addComponent(label);
    }

    @Override
    public void enter(ViewChangeEvent event) {

        System.out.println("Admin ENTER begin:" + event.getParameters());

        String v = event.getParameters();
        if (v.isEmpty())
            label.setValue(++count + " : Admin EMPTY EVENT");
        else
            label.setValue(++count + " : " + v);

        System.out.println("Admin ENTER finish");
    }

}
```

Follwing is another view code for view change effect testing.

```
package kr.re.nsr.secdiv.inseog.navi.testnavi;

import com.vaadin.navigator.View;
import com.vaadin.navigator.ViewChangeListener.ViewChangeEvent;
import com.vaadin.ui.Button;
import com.vaadin.ui.Label;
import com.vaadin.ui.UI;
import com.vaadin.ui.VerticalLayout;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class QueryView extends VerticalLayout implements View {

    Label label = null;
    static int count = 0;

    public QueryView() {

        setMargin(true);
        setSpacing(true);

        UI.getCurrent().getPage().addUriFragmentChangedListener(ev -> {
            String fragment = ev.getUriFragment();
            if(!fragment.startsWith("!query"))
                return;
            label.setValue("Query : " + count + "/" + fragment);
        });

        Button btnAAA = new Button("Query aaa", e -> {
            this.getUI().getPage().setUriFragment("!query/aaa", true);
        });

        Button btnBBB = new Button("Query bbb", e -> {
            this.getUI().getPage().setUriFragment("!query/bbb", true);
        });

        Button btnAdmin = new Button("Goto admin", e -> {
            TestNavi.navigator.navigateTo("admin");
        });

        label = new Label();

        addComponent(btnAAA);
        addComponent(btnBBB);
        addComponent(btnAdmin);
        addComponent(label);
    }

    @Override
    public void enter(ViewChangeEvent event) {

        System.out.println("Query ENTER begin:" + event.getParameters());

        String v = event.getParameters();
        if (v.isEmpty())
            label.setValue(++count + " : Query EMPTY EVENT");
        else
            label.setValue(++count + " : " + v);

        System.out.println("Query ENTER finish");
    }

}
```

Follwing is main control UI which defines navigator objects.

```
package kr.re.nsr.secdiv.inseog.navi.testnavi;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;

import com.vaadin.annotations.Theme;
import com.vaadin.annotations.VaadinServletConfiguration;
import com.vaadin.annotations.Widgetset;
import com.vaadin.navigator.Navigator;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinRequest;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet;
import com.vaadin.ui.UI;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Theme("TestNavi")
@Widgetset("kr.re.nsr.secdiv.inseog.navi.testnavi.WidgeTestNavi")
public class TestNavi extends UI {

    public static Navigator navigator = null;
    private QueryView qv = null;
    private AdminView av = null;
    private StartView sv = null;

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest vaadinRequest) {

        navigator = new Navigator(this, this);
        qv = new QueryView();
        av = new AdminView();
        sv = new StartView();

        getPage().setTitle("서인석이 시험중입니다.");

        navigator.addView("", sv);
        navigator.addView("query", qv);
        navigator.addView("admin", av);
    }

    @WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/*", name = "TestNaviServlet", asyncSupported = true)
    @VaadinServletConfiguration(ui = TestNavi.class, productionMode = false)
    public static class TestNaviServlet extends VaadinServlet {
    }
}
```

Following is starting View.

```
package kr.re.nsr.secdiv.inseog.navi.testnavi;

import com.vaadin.navigator.View;
import com.vaadin.navigator.ViewChangeListener.ViewChangeEvent;
import com.vaadin.ui.VerticalLayout;
import com.vaadin.ui.Alignment;
import com.vaadin.ui.Button;
import com.vaadin.ui.Button.ClickEvent;
import com.vaadin.ui.Notification;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class StartView extends VerticalLayout implements View {

    public StartView() {

        setSizeFull();

        Button button = new Button("GO to Main View", new Button.ClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
                TestNavi.navigator.navigateTo("query");             
            }
        });

        addComponent(button);
        setComponentAlignment(button, Alignment.MIDDLE_CENTER);

    }

    @Override
    public void enter(ViewChangeEvent event) {
        Notification.show("TestNavi");
    }

}
```

Solution keypoint is as follow.

1. Add **URI fragment handler** for each view.
2. For status change within view, use **setUriFragment**.
3. For setUriFragment, do not forget to **use ! as first character**.
4. Finally, fragment change handler must **check fragment string owenership**. If the string is not yours, return immediately. Another handler will do their roles.

This is solution for Vaadin 7.2.7 version release. Until v7.6.6., navigateTo do well within single view status change. But v7.6.7 navigateTo does not fire enter event for fragment change within view.
Vaadin may restore enter fire logic somedays.